# PHP not displaying errors when using PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

When using PHPUnit from the terminal PHP is not reporting any errors if a PHP error exists within the php file. Here is an example file I am using:

```
<?php

class AssertionsTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testException()
    {
        new NonExistantClass;
    }
}
```

Clearly the NonExistantClass does no exist. When running PHPUnit, all I am getting is this:

```
jamesjeffery$ phpunit AssertionsTest.php
    PHPUnit 3.7.19 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

No PHP errors.

I am using PHP 5.4.10. I have error reporting set to E_ALL and display_errors set to on.

Any idea's what could be happening?

Comment: Are they errors being dumped to apache logs?

Comment: I ran your code and received the error.  I gave it the file name I saved.  Are you sure your PHP file name is AssertionsTest.php and not something else?